# Identifier undefined when called by reference in function

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to pass a vector of "Piece"s (a class I define) by reference into a function, however during compile time I get an error saying "Piece" is undefined. The files currently looks like:

**Header.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H // Will only be true the once!
#define MY_CLASS_H
#include <vector>
//some stuff    
bool make_move(std::vector<Piece*> & vector_of_pieces);
class Piece {
//member functions declarations
};
#endif
```

**nonPieceFunctions.cpp**

```
#include "Header.hpp"
#include<iostream>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

bool make_move(vector<Piece*> &vector_of_pieces) {
    string piece_location, piece_new_location;
    cout << "Which piece would you like to move?" << endl;
    while (is_valid_input(piece_location) == false) { //checks input is of the right format
        cin >> piece_location;
    }
    int file_no = get_file_no(piece_location); //gets file number from user input
    int rank_no = get_rank_no(piece_location); //gets rank number from user input
    cout << "File no is " << file_no << endl;
    cout << "Rank no is " << rank_no << endl;
    return true;
}
```

This is not the complete version of the function I want to make but it currently doesn't compile as it is. No functions in "make_move" are member functions of any class.

Comment: I observe that `make_move` doesn't actually use `vector_of_pieces`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands

```
bool make_move(std::vector<Piece*> & vector_of_pieces);
```

comes before the definition of `Piece`, hence your problem.

Either move this after the class definition.

Or forward declare as follows:

```
class Piece;
bool make_move(std::vector<Piece*> & vector_of_pieces);
```

since you are using a pointer in the vector it should work.

BTW - are you deleting these pointers somewhere?

Comment: I suspect in this particular case, the `vector_of_pieces` contains non-owning pointers - which won't need deleting.  (Or possibly that the code just leaks them ... but as there are only at most 32 pieces involved in a game of chess, who cares?)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Yeah it's a chess game so I delete the pointers when a piece is taken. I think a using `std::map` would have been better instead of `std::vector` but it's too late now to change it I think

Answer (score 1):

Either implement the class Piece before the deceleration of make_move():

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H // Will only be true the once!
#define MY_CLASS_H
#include <vector>
//some stuff 
class Piece {
//member functions declarations
};
bool make_move(std::vector<Piece*> & vector_of_pieces);

#endif
```

or use forward deceleration on the class:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H // Will only be true the once!
#define MY_CLASS_H
#include <vector>
//some stuff 
class Piece;   
bool make_move(std::vector<Piece*> & vector_of_pieces);
class Piece {
//member functions declarations
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Piece` in `make_move`' s declaration, you need to tell the compiler that it will follow later:

```
class Piece;
bool make_move(std::vector<Piece*> & vector_of_pieces);

class Piece {
//member functions declarations
};
```